# Counting Instance number for Categories in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a sensor output data file as :

```
category   <tab> instance <space> instance2 <space> ... instanceN
category2  <tab> instanceX <space> instanceY <space> ... instanceZ
```

Now for every instance, I need to count how many categories have this particular instance.
I am new to pig, can anyone suggest, how should I go about this problem?

Comment: Can you describe you data a little more? Do you have the same number of columns for each row? Do you use the same delimiter for instances?

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is tab for category and instance list. Within instances, it is separated by spaces. Also the column length will vary.

Comment: You mean,for each category you need to find the total number of instances? category = <total number of instances in first row>, category2=<total number of instances in second row>. Please clarify?

Comment: For every instance : instance, instance2 .... instanceN Instance X instance .... Z, I need to count how many categories have this particular instance. Thus how many rows have this instance under a category.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
input.txt
category        instance instance2 instanceN
category1       instanceX instanceY instanceZ
category2       instance instanceY

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (category:chararray,instances:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE category,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(instances,' '));
C = GROUP B BY $1;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group,COUNT($1);
DUMP D;

Output:
(instance,2)
(instance2,1)
(instanceN,1)
(instanceX,1)
(instanceY,2)
(instanceZ,1)
```